# Why can't I log in when there is no flood table?

Tags: 8

In the database there isn't any *flood* table, but I get this error message.

> There have been more than 5 failed login attempts for this account. It is temporarily blocked.

What could not allow me to log in?

Answer (score 13):

Drupal 8 still exited table flood. You can see [here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Flood!DatabaseBackend.php/class/DatabaseBackend/8.2.x). Table **flood** created when use login failed. You can use the way in drupal 7. Simple

```
drush php-eval 'db_query("DELETE FROM `flood`");'
```

[Full document.](https://www.drupal.org/node/1023440)

Comment: You can also install the [flood unblock](https://www.drupal.org/project/flood_unblock) module to manage this.

Comment: If it is the primary user who is locked out and you do not have command line access you have to wait 1 hour before trying again [if I have read correctly](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Flood%21DatabaseBackend.php/function/DatabaseBackend%3A%3Aregister/8.2.x)

Comment: In Drupal 9 db_query has been removed. You can use `drush sqlq "DELETE FROM flood"`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Flood Contro](https://www.drupal.org/project/flood_control)l Module.

> Flood Control provides an interface for hidden flood control variables
> (e.g. login attempt limiters) and makes it possible for site
> administrators to remove IP addresses and user ID's from the flood
> table.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a flood table, then you are not using Drupal's default flood control mechanism.

So the first step is to identify what mechanism you are on using.  On Drupal SaaS like PlatformSH and Pantheon, it is common to use Redis.  Redis can be configured to handle flood control instead of Drupal.

In such a case, you need to clear the Redis keystore.  One way to do this is to use the redis-cli to connect to Redis and then delete all the keys with `flushall`.  This assumes you are using Redis in an ephemeral configuration and do not need to keep the keys.