# How can I switch from Redis flood control back to Drupal's default flood control?

Tags: authentication-authorization, 10

Related question: [Why can't I log in when there is no flood table?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/213860/what-could-not-allow-me-to-log-in)
I have a Drupal 10 site hosted on PlatformSH that has Redis enabled.  I have the Redis module enabled.

On a test domain, my test account got blocked due to too many failed login attempts.  So, I tried to unblock the user using the Flood Control module:

`drush flood_unblock:all`

However, I get an error:

In ExceptionHandler.php line 56:

```
  SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'db.flood' doesn't exist: SELECT "f"."fid" AS "fid"  
  FROM                                                                                                           
  "flood" "f"                                                                                                    
  WHERE "event" = :db_condition_placeholder_0; Array                                                             
  (                                                                                                              
      [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => user.failed_login_ip                                                      
  )
```

This is because Redis replaces the flood control interface.

In `services.yml`, Redis is set to replace the default flood backend:

```
  # Replaces the default flood backend with a redis implementation.
  flood:
    class: Drupal\Core\Flood\FloodInterface
    factory: ['@redis.flood.factory', get]
```

So, to reverse this, I commented out these lines and ran `drush cr`, but Drupal did not create a flood table for me.

How do I go back to using Drupal's default flood control?

Comment: `I don't know where to look` You should look at the **[platform.sh documentation](https://docs.platform.sh/guides/drupal/redis.html)** specially the part that says `// You can leverage Redis by using it for the lock and flood control systems` ... `// To do so, apply the following changes to the container configuration.`

Comment: @NoSssweat Thanks, I missed that in the docs.  Now I have a much clearer problem, so I updated the question.

Comment: The flood table is (or at least used to be, can’t check right now) created on demand, so won’t exist until someone is blocked